# transfer data from table to another table in erlang

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have in my database mnesia two table  which have this syntax :

```
-record(person, {firstname, lastname,adress}).
-record(personBackup, {firstname, lastname,adress}).
```

I want to transfer the data from the table **person** to the table **personBackup**

I think that I should create the two tables with this syntax ( I'm agree with your idea)

```
mnesia:create_table(person,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)}]),
mnesia:create_table(person_backup,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
```

now I have a function named  **verify**

in this function I will do a test and if the test is verified I should transfert data from **person** to **person_backup** and then I should do a **reset**

this is my function

```
verify(Form)->

if Form =:= 40 ->

%%here I should transert data from person to person_backup  : read all lines from person and write this lines into person_backup

reset();

Form =/= 40 ->
io:format("it is ok")
end.
```

this is the function **reset** :

```
reset() ->
    stop(),
    destroy(),
    create(),
    start(),
    {ok}.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a separate record definition for each table.  [mnesia:create_table](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2) takes a `record_name` option, so you could create your tables like this:

```
mnesia:create_table(person,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)}]),
mnesia:create_table(person_backup,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
```

The value for `record_name` defaults to the name of the table, so there's no need to specify it for `person`.  (I changed `personBackup` to `person_backup`, as Erlang atoms are usually written without camel case, unlike variables.)

Then you can put the same kind of records in both tables.  Read or select from `person`, and write to `person_backup`, no conversion necessary.

Comment: I think we should read all lines from the table person and after that we should write this lines into the table person_backup

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a seperated record definition for each table. Variables 90 and 80 will do the trick. If you wish to take a option of recod_name, you could use mnesia:create_table

@ legoscia, you are correct for everything except for line 6.

mnesia:create_table(person, if player value = 1

> this way the outcome can disc all copies and nodes.

Comment: can you please more clarify your answer specifically about this line mnesia:create_table(person, if player value = 1, and as I said I want to transfer data from table to another table , so we should read all data from the first table then transfer this data to the second table